# Why is the direct product $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ undefined when $\mathbb{R}$ is viewed as a field?

Tags: category-theory, definition, direct-product

Reading through the Wiki article on direct products (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product), an example is given using the set of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, viewed as a set endowed with different algebraic structures. In all cases the underlying set of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is (of course) $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, when considering $\mathbb{R}$ as a field, the article states that the direct product is undefined, since the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the naïve addition $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and multiplication $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,bd)$ is clearly not a field.

My problem is that the set $\mathbb{R}^2$ **can** be endowed with a multiplicative structure that makes it into a field (since $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$ as a set), so my question is the following:

> Why can we **not** define $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{C}$, when viewing $\mathbb{R}$ as the field of real numbers?

Is there an implicit assumption in the definition of direct product that if $X$ has some algebraic operation $*$, then $X\times X$ must have the corresponding operation $*_{\times}$ defined as $(x_1,x_2)*_{\times}(y_1,y_2):=(x_1 * y_1,x_2 * y_2)$? If so, is this because of the way the direct product is defined in category theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A product $A \times B$ also comes with a pair of projection maps $\pi_1: A \times B \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_2: A \times B \rightarrow B$. These are a fundamental part of the definition of a direct product.

We want these projections to be morphisms in the category we're considering. In this case, we want them to be ring homomorphisms, so they need to preserve the operations of the ring. Using this, we can prove that the operation of the product has to be as expected.

$$\pi_1((x_1,x_2)*_{\times}(y_1,y_2)) = \pi_1(x_1,x_2) *\pi_1(y_1,y_2) = x_1 * y_1$$

So the first entry of the result under the operation has to be $x_1 * y_1$. The same idea works for the second element, giving $(x_1,x_2)*_{\times}(y_1,y_2):=(x_1 * y_1,x_2 * y_2)$.

If you try to define the product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself as $\mathbb{C}$, you find that no pair of projection maps can work, in part because any ring homomorphism out of a field must be injective.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. To prove that no canonical projections can be found, is it possible to think about it in the following way? 
"since the category of fields is a subcategory of the category of rings, we have that $X\times Y$ the field must also be $X\times Y$ the ring. Therefore, we know what the ring structure of $X\times Y$ the field must be (if it exists), and hence we know that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ the field is $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ the ring, if defined. The latter, however, is not a field, hence we conclude that the direct product is not defined."

Comment: @Scounged Your reasoning is incorrect. If $C$ is a subcategory of $D$, then $C$ and $D$ may both have products without the two agreeing. For a dual example, fix a singleton set $T = \{\star\}$ (doesn’t matter what $\star$ is). Let $D$ be the category of sets, and let $C$ be the full subcategory consisting of subsets of $T$. Then coproducts in $C$ are calculated by taking the union, but coproducts in $D$ are taken via the disjoint union. So $T \coprod T$ in $C$ has a single element, while $T \coprod T$ in $D$ has two elements; hence, the two coproducts are not isomorphic.

Comment: @MarkSaving Just to clarify a bit in the example you gave, is it just that my reasoning is faulty for the direct product in the same way that analogous reasoning would be wrong for coproducts? If so, is there any way to "save" my line of reasoning, or is it just a lost cause?

Comment: @Scounged Yes. If you consider the opposite categories $C^{op}$ and $D^{op}$, we’ve come up with an example where products exist in both categories but don’t agree. Your reasoning likely cannot be salvaged since $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ exists in both $Ring$ and $Field$ but the two don’t agree (the product is $\mathbb{Q}$ in $Field$). Perhaps you could come up with some argument that applies to $\mathbb{R}$ but not $\mathbb{Q}$, but that would very likely require the use of something very complex.

Answer (score 5):

Chessanator has answered the stated question, but one might plausibly ask whether there is any way to take the product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in the category of fields.

The answer is no. For such a product consists of a field $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ together with two projection maps $\pi_1, \pi_2 : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which are field homomorphisms.

Now consider the diagonal map $\Delta : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Note that $\pi_i \circ \Delta$ is the identity map for $i = 1, 2$. Since each $\pi_i$ is a field homomorphism and hence injective, it follows that each $\pi_i$ is a bijection with $\Delta$ its inverse. Thus, we have $\pi_1 = \pi_2$, and without loss of generality, we can take the product to be $\mathbb{R}$ with the projections the identity map.

It’s easy to conclude based on this fact that for any field $k$, there is at most one field homomorphism $k \to \mathbb{R}$.

Now consider, for instance, $k = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. There are two maps $f, g : k \to \mathbb{R}$ sending $\sqrt{2}$ to $\pm \sqrt{2}$. So we have arrived at our contradiction.

Comment: More generally, $A\hookleftarrow C\to B$ (where $A\hookleftarrow C$ is a monomorphism) is a product structure only if for each morphism $D\to A$ there is at most one morphism $D\to B$, i.e. only if $C$ is subterminal in that there is at most one morphism $D\to C$, and also and only if $B$ has no monic endomorphisms. In particular, only fields with no endomorphisms and a common subfield (i.e. of the same characteristic) could have products, in which case the product is the largest common subfield (which I think might always exist).

Comment: Looking up the diagonal morphism on the wiki page, there are no references but rather just an assertion that the diagonal morphism $\Delta:X\rightarrow X\times X$ always exists when the direct product is well-defined. Is this some sort of "folklore" result in category theory, and how is it proven?

Comment: @Scounged The diagonal morphism is the morphism satisfying $\Delta \circ \pi_i = 1_X$ for $i = 1, 2$. If we’re considering the category of sets and $X = \mathbb{R}$, the function $\Delta(x) = (x, x)$ is the diagonal map and traces out a diagonal line on the plane.

Comment: Oh right, it comes directly from the universal property, so it has to exist by definition of direct product!