# In the category of fields, is $k\times k=k$ if the direct product is well-defined (in the category of fields)?

Tags: category-theory, field-theory, direct-product

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407040/why-is-the-direct-product-mathbbr-times-mathbbr-undefined-when-mathbbr/4407057?noredirect=1#comment9221585_4407057) on why the direct product $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is not well-defined, where a proof was given to show that there is no way to construct it without reaching a contradiction. However, to me it seems like the main method in the proof could be used to prove something more general:

"Given a field $k$, let us assume that the direct product $k\times k$ is well-defined in the category of fields, with canonical projections $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ (which are automatically injective since morphisms in the category of fields are always injective). By the universal property defining $k\times k$, there exists a morphism $\Delta:k\rightarrow k\times k$ that is the inverse of both of them, implying that $\pi_1=\pi_2$, and hence we may set $k\times k=k$, with $\pi_1=\pi_2$ being the identity map on $k$, without loss of generality. Moreover, using the universal property once more, we see that this immediately implies that for any field $k'$, there is at most one morphism $k'\rightarrow k$."

Right now I don't see any error in the above line of reasoning, and if I'm correct we can make the following conclusions:

> Let $k$ be a field. If $k\times k$ is well-defined as a field, then
>
> 1. $k\times k=k$, and
> 2. For every field $k'$, there is at most one morphism $k'\rightarrow k$.

However, if we make the assumption that for every field $k'$, there is at most one morphism $k'\rightarrow k$, then if I'm not mistaken we can pretty easily just define the direct product $k\times k$ to be $k$ without any issue. As a result, we would get the following.

> Let $k$ be a field. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $k\times k$ is well-defined in the category of fields.
> 2. For every field $k'$ there is at most one morphism $k'\rightarrow k$.

From my previous question I was given that if $k=\mathbb{Q}$ then $k\times k$ is indeed $k$, but I'm not sure exactly how one would prove this. Thus, I have the following questions:

> 1. Is my reasoning and conclusions about the direct product of fields correct?
> 2. If so, how can we most easily prove that there is at most one morphism $k\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ for any field $k$?
> 3. Are there any other well-known examples of fields that have a well-defined direct product (as a field)?

Comment: What do you mean by “assume $k\times k$ is well-defined?” That seems like a big assumption. If $k\times k$ is exists in the category of fields, sure, it can only be $k.$ But that doesn’t show it exists. There are reasons we don’t generally work in the category of fields…

Comment: For example, if there is an automorphism $\phi:k\to k,$ then that function plus $\operatorname{id}_k:k\to k$ must give a map $k\to k\times k,$ with the appropriate properties, but then we get $\phi=\operatorname{id}_k.$ So for $k\times k$ to exist, $k$ must have no non-trivial automorphisms. That rules out a lot of fields. This rules out a LOT of fields.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This is partly why I asked the question to begin with; as you stated, we get some pretty severe restrictions on the field $k$, so I wanted to make sure I hadn't made any serious error in my reasoning. When searching online I could only see the direct product $k\times k$ in the category of rings being considered, hence my post here.

Comment: In general, the category of fields is to the category or rings as the category of simple groups is to the category of groups. We generally don’t concern ourselves with the category of fields, because fails to have a lot of useful constructions.

Comment: Every ring homomorphism between fields is injective. $\mathbb{Q}$ (and the other prime fields) have no proper subfields so any homomorphism from a field to $\mathbb{Q}$ must be an isomorphism. Furthermore $\mathbb{Q}$ has only one automorphism so there is at most one isomorphism between an arbitrary field and $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, as you say, there is at most one homomorphism to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Other fields that have a $k\times k$ are the prime fields $\mathbb F_p.$ That is because are no automorphism. I’d guess $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb F_p$ are the only fields with no automorphisms, but I’m not sure. (You don’t need automorphisms, just some non-trivial endomorhpisms $k\to k,$ to get a problem for the existence of $k\times k.$ But I can’t think of an example where there is a non-trivial endomorphism where there isn’t also a non-trivial automorphism.)

Comment: Also, if you can find two distinct $K\mapsto k$ for some $k,K,$ then they contradict $k\times k.$ So this makes it easier to prove $\mathbb R$ does not have this property. There are automorphisms of $\mathbb R,$ but they are non-constructive. But it is easy to show two distinct maps $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)\to\mathbb R.$ But there are still fields like $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2),$ which have no automorphisms.

Comment: Any proper field extension of $\mathbb F_p$ definitely has a non-trivial endomorphism, since $\alpha\mapsto \alpha^p$ is always a field endomorphism of $\mathbb F_p,$ and the elements of $\mathbb F_p$ are the $p$ solutions to $x^p=x.$ So we are really down to fields extension of $\mathbb Q$ which  have no non-trivial automorphism.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No, there are no non-trivial automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ (or even non-trivial endomorphisms). To see this, note that any endomorphism preserves the order (since $a\leq b$ if and only if $b-a$ is a square) and $\mathbb{Q}$ is an order-dense subset which is fixed by any endomorphism.

Comment: Whoops, yes, so you really do need a subfield with an automorphism to show that $k=\mathbb R$ doesn’t work. @AlexKruckman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any fields $k,K$ and two distinct field inclusions $\phi_1,\phi_2:K\mapsto k,$ we can preclude that $k\times k$ exists.

This is because, if $k\times k$ exists,  $\phi_1\times\phi_2:K\to k\times k.$  By your argument, since $\pi_1=\pi_2,$ we must get $$\phi_1=\pi_1\circ (\phi_1\times \phi_2)=\pi_2\circ(\phi_1\times \phi_2)=\phi_2,$$ contradicting that the $\phi_i$ are distinct.

Now, every field contains either $\mathbb F_p$ for some prime or $\mathbb Q.$

If $k\cong \mathbb F_p$ or $k\cong\mathbb Q,$ the only field maps $K\to k$ are isomorphisms, and the  only automorphism is the identity, so $k\times k$ can be shown to exist.

If $k$ contains $\mathbb F_p$ but is not isomorphic, then there is an non-trivial endomorphism $k\to k$ defined as $\phi:\alpha\mapsto \alpha^p.$ It is non-trivial because $x^p=x$ can have at most $p$ roots, and all the elements of $\mathbb F_p$ are roots.

But this means we have two distinct morphisms $k\to k,$ with one the identity, the other $\phi.$

So this leaves fields which contain $\mathbb Q.$

We know that given any field containing $\mathbb Q$ and an element $\alpha$ transcendental over $\mathbb Q$ gives two morphisms:

$$\mathbb Q(x)\to k$$

one sending $x\mapsto \alpha,$ and one $x\mapsto \alpha^{-1}.$

So $k$ cannot contain any transcendental over $\mathbb Q.$

Also, if $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q,$ with minimal rational polynomial $p(x),$ then $\alpha$ can be the only root of $p(x)$ in $k.$ If there is another root $\beta\in k,$ then there are two inclusions $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\to k,$ sending $x\mapsto \alpha,\beta.$

So we’ve reduced to cases like $k=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2),$ where no algebraic conjugates of any element is contained in the field.

I think in these cases, we actually get $k\times k$ existing, because there is at most one morphism $K\to k$ for each field $K,$ and thus the axioms of the product are confirmed.

I’m not sure how to characterize these fields more precisely. My Galois theory is rusty - maybe there is a term for such a field.

Comment: Repeating my comment from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407040#comment9221961_4408652: more generally two objects in a category every morphism of which is a monomorphism have a product only if they are both subterminal (at most one morphism from any other field). For fields, it is additionally necessary that both have the same characteristic, in which case they have a common extension and their product would be the maximal subfield of both when the two are considered as subfields of the common extension.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I agree with your comment, but note that the two fields may have multiple non-isomorphic amalgamations. For example, two copies of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ can be amalagamated in such a way that the maximal common subfield (their intersection) is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman good point! The counter-example is the splitting field. It would be the maximal common subfield among all such amalgamations that is the product (whether such a maximal extension always exist for fields with no embedding of one to the other is less clear). I wonder if there's a maximal extension of Q for which each polynomial has at most one root.